# Associate an email with a Publication List

Tags: marketing-cloud

Here is the use case.

We have a set of emails and would like to tag them to different publication lists. The only way to do this as per my understanding is to change the publication list during send. Is there a way, we can tag the email beforehand. We are trying to prevent the individual senders from doing the manual association.

The only place I have seen this in Triggered Sends in Journey Builder.

Answer (score 1):

At this point in time, it is not possible to "tag" an email to default to a particular publication list for sends within Content Builder. You can, as you've suggested, define a publication list in User Initiated Sends (including Automation Studio activities), Triggered Sends (including Journey Builder), and Salesforce sends.

My recommendation would be to make sure your users are trained in the correct use of Publication List selection and that there is a QA/approval process that includes checking that the correct Pub List is chosen before send.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a User-Initiated Email Interaction - in there, you can "tie" your email to a list of recipients, including a publication list, plus define the sender profile, etc. 
You will be able to re-use it, without the need to configure it each time.

Go to `Email Studio > Interactions > User-Initiated Emails` or read more here:

[**Create a User-Initiated Email Interaction**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_user_initiated_email_interaction.htm&type=5)